# Drag & Drop ImageIcons into an array of ImageIcons, save array

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, drag-and-drop

I have an array of plain white ImageIcons, I drag and drop other ImageIcons to construct a story using images. If I wanted to store this array to a database, would the array hold the ImageIcons I have placed here, or would it hold the original plain white ImageIcons. The images are already stored in a database, via their path.

Secondly, the story would never go above 10 Images so would it be best to save the array as one record to a database, with a storyID and each ImageIcon entered into a field of it's own.

I'm just wondering is what I'm trying to do possible?
If this is more like 2 question I will remove the second half on request.

THis is the code being used to drag from one JPanel to the other.

```
   TransferHandler handler = new TransferHandler("icon") { 
    @Override public boolean canImport(TransferSupport support) 
    { return super.canImport(support) && support.getComponent().getParent() != ImageSelectPanel; } }; 

    MouseListener listener = new MouseAdapter(){ 
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){ 
JComponent c = (JComponent) e.getSource(); 
TransferHandler handler = c.getTransferHandler(); handler.exportAsDrag(c, e, TransferHandler.COPY); }
```

Comment: Could we see some code to see the layout, or are you not at that step yet? What are you using for the drag-and-drop functionality? jQuery Sortable? Something else? If all you are asking is if it is doable, then sure. Peck away at it, and let us know if you run across issues. :)

Comment: @king14nyr what does the UI technology have to do with storing the data?

Comment: @AndreiBodnarescu If we had some idea as to what the UI was, it would give us a better idea as to how to store it. I have examples of jQuery sortable serializing and storing data. That might give him a start towards his goal. But, without tech details on how he is planning on doing this, I don't know how much programming help we can offer. :/

Comment: Please edit code into the question (using code formatting).  If you are replying to someone, add @PersonName before the comment.

Comment: @king14nyr I have added in the code I am using to drag and drop the Icons, this only allows the Icons to be transferred one way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, the best way to go here is to store pointers (or ids) towards your icon images when saving a certain sequence of such images (a story).

Now as to how to actually persist those images, if they're small in size and numbers (something like no more than 50 Kb each, no more then 10-20 images) you can save them all as BLOBs in your SQL database, and then refference their ids in subsequent stories you save.

Otherwise, if they're bigger/more than that you'd do better to just store them on disk, preferrably a separate disk than the one where your database resides, and just keep the file location in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The selection of imageicons that can be dragged and dropped into the array of the plain white icons are actually already stored in my Database and read and displayed in my gui. I simply drag them to the space on the story I want them in.
I decided to do this storing their path rather than as BLOB files.

Im just unsure how to go about storing that array of images.